# UWP ContentDialog covers whole page

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, themes

When `ContentDialog` is used with a color theme from [Fluent XAML Theme Editor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/fluent-xaml-theme-editor/9n2xd3q8x57c), content dialog covers the whole page

To replicate follow these steps:

1. Create new UWP app
2. Grab a color scheme from [Fluent XAML Theme Editor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/fluent-xaml-theme-editor/9n2xd3q8x57c) and add it to your project
3. In App.Xaml add this:

```
     <Application.Resources>
      <ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
           <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
      </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
     </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

5. Add a `TextBlock` and `Loaded` event to `MainPage`
6. Add `ContentDialog` call to `Loaded` event

```
   private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ContentDialog noWifiDialog = new ContentDialog
            {
                Title = "No wifi connection",
                Content = "Check your connection and try again.",
                CloseButtonText = "Ok"
            };

            _ = await noWifiDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
```

7. Run the app and see how `ContentDialog` covers up the `TextBlock`. If you remove the color theme this does not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is not the dialog *covering* anything, but the normal background dimming feature of [Content Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/dialogs-and-flyouts/dialogs) boxes.

The Fluent XAML Theme Editor output has simply altered the styles which make the default background a solid colour, in my theme that was white, but instead I would like the user to still see the content in the background.

This is the style key that you need to manage:

```
SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush
```

Add this snippet to a resource dictionary that is applied *after* your reference to the main theme file, it will set the background to an opaque color for all content dialog boxes, defineing in this way will allow you to support a different background colour in dark or light modes, this example uses the same colour for each theme, but demonstrates how to define a different one:

```
<!--  override the Dialog Background  -->
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ContentDialogDimmingThemeBrush" Color="#99FFFFFF" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush" Color="#99000000" />
        <StaticResource x:Key="ContentDialogLightDismissOverlayBackground" ResourceKey="SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ContentDialogDimmingThemeBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorHighlightColor}" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush" Color="#99000000" />
        <StaticResource x:Key="ContentDialogLightDismissOverlayBackground" ResourceKey="SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```

You could do this inline or move it to another file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>


            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Default">
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ContentDialogDimmingThemeBrush" Color="#99FFFFFF" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush" Color="#99000000" />
                        <StaticResource x:Key="ContentDialogLightDismissOverlayBackground" ResourceKey="SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush" />
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ContentDialogDimmingThemeBrush" Color="{ThemeResource SystemColorHighlightColor}" />
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush" Color="#99000000" />
                        <StaticResource x:Key="ContentDialogLightDismissOverlayBackground" ResourceKey="SystemControlPageBackgroundMediumAltMediumBrush" />
                    </ResourceDictionary>
                </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>


        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I added this to the project but it does not resolve the issue. dialog box still covers/obscures the entire page behind it. Also, none of the keys you want added are in the theme dictionary, so not sure why did they get overwritten by the the theme...

Comment: @under Can you show a screenshot to explain, showing the before and after. I followed your instructions and this worked for me.

Comment: I've updated, I didn't notice I had customized my theme file

Comment: Thant works, thanks! If I remove ContentDialogDimmingThemeBrush it still works. What does that do?

Comment: One problem, it makes the dialog box somewhat transparent. Which property is that? Background? I don;t quite understand how theme managed to break this when none of these properties were changed by the theme!

Comment: I generally leave `ContentDialogDimmingThemeBrush` and `ContentDialogLightDismissOverlayBackground` because many 3rd party dialog implementations from earlier versions of the windows runtime used one of these, they are the only resources where the key logically fits the area that is being colored behind the dialog, but you're correct, they are not technically necessary in the current runtime version. If you don't like the background being dimmed at all, change the color and the opacity that color.